# How can I sell an item on behalf of my corporation?

Tags: eve-online

In EVE online there is a role called 'Trader' - which allows you to buy and sell items on behalf of your corporation. I have this role on my character, but whenever I try and sell an item from a corporate hangar at one of our offices, I only have the option to sell the item on behalf of myself.

Have I misunderstood the purpose of this option? Ideally I'd like to be able to list items on the market, but then once these items have sold I'd like the payment to be provided straight to the corporation wallet, rather than to my character.

Is this possible within EVE online?  How can I sell an item on behalf of my corporation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have access to one of the corporate wallets to buy/sell on behalf of your corporation. Make sure to set that wallet as your active corporate wallet (wallet/corporation tab). You should see a small box at the bottom of the buy/sell window saying "Use corporation account X" where X is the current corporate wallet you have active, tick that and it goes on the corporation's tab.

Additionally, note that any item bought using the corporate wallet will appear in the 'Deliveries' hangar at a station - *not* your personal hangar.

Comment: Will this result in the payment when an item is purchased being deposited into your corporate wallet?

Comment: Into whichever corporate wallet you have set as active, yes. If you tick the box, any funds needed to complete the transaction will be drawn from the corporate account, if it has enough liquid ISK (in the case of a buy).

Comment: I confirm this. +1 for telling about the "deliveries" thing when *buying* for your corporaion, this puzzled me for a few days when I first tried...